# How to read numbers separated by spaces and remove duplicates?

Tags: python

I am currently doing an assignment in which I need to read in user input separated by spaces into a list named `list1`. I then need to iterate over that list and all unique numbers need to be added to a different list name `list2`.

Finally, I need to print the numbers sorted like `1 2 3 4 5 6` with spaces.

#### Code

```python
list1 = input('Enter numbers seperated by spaces: ')
list2 = []
    
for num in list1:
    if num not in list2:
        list2.append(num)
    
print(f'The distinct numbers are: {list2}')
```

Here is the output that I need to fix.

```
Write in a string of numbers seperated by a space for each: 3 4 5 6 2
The distinct numbers are: ['3', ' ', '4', '5', '6', '2']
```

Comment: [https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

Comment: See also [**Removing duplicates in the lists**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7961363/1164465).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to split up the input. Python strings have a built in [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) function for just this purpose.

Next, you want to ensure that any empty values are removed. In the example below, the list comprehension checks if each user input item evaluates to `True` (i.e. not a blank string) and also converts the strings to integers, which is important to sort numerically rather than [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order).

The `set` data type is a container that does not allow duplicates, so you can initialize a new set from the list of numbers to remove duplicates.

The built-in [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) function can be used to sort the data.

And lastly, the [`join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) function can be used to create a string with each number separated by a space, but in order for this to work, the numbers need to be converted back to strings. Here, the `str` class creates new strings from each number, which are then passed to `join()`.

#### Code sample

```python
user_input = input('Enter numbers separated by spaces: ')
string_list = user_input.split()
number_list = [int(x) for x in string_list if x]
unique_numbers = set(number_list)
sorted_list = sorted(unique_numbers)

print(f'You entered distinct values: {" ".join(map(str, sorted_list))}')
```

#### Example run

```
Enter numbers seperated by spaces: 3  4  3 5 32 1 5  4
You entered distinct values: 1 3 4 5 32
```